# I have many analytics calls to be sent how to buffer them and flush within a certain period if buffer not full

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that has to send analytics data using custom code.
I don't wish to send the data each time I receive a record but instead buffer them and send them in bulks of X elements.
If for example The bulk size is 10 and I received only 5 within 2 minutes, I need to send all of them and start over.

I used the term buffer because I didn't find a better way to describe it.
What is the best way to implement such thing ? Are there existing APIs that implements the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

```
public class Sender implements Runnable {
  public CountDownLatch recordCount;
  public sender(CountDownLatch recordCount) {
     this.recordCount = recordCount;
  }
  public void run() {
    recordCount.await(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // this will stop waiting after 2 minutes or countDown is complete
    //send records in buffer
  }
}

public class Receiver implements Runnable {
  public CountDownLatch recordCount;
  public receiver(CountDownLatch recordCount) {
     this.recordCount = recordCount;
  }
  public void run() {
    //recieve and add to buffer
    recordCount.countDown(); // this will deceremnt the count
  }
}
```